# Vigenere cs50 doesn't complain when lacks second arg

Tags: c, vigenere, cs50

I don't understand why it isn't working. It complains when there are 3 or more args but not when there is only the one Vigenere arg. I have looked at other people who had same problem and they said this worked to resolve.....not sure what I am missing here. When I run `./vigenere`, I get a segmentation fault. It works normally with 2 arg like `./vigenere bard` and complains when extra arguments are given like `./vigenere bard dfads`.

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>




int main(int argc,string argv[])
{  

string sKeyWord = argv[1];                   
int iKeyLength = strlen(sKeyWord);           
int iKey[iKeyLength];                        
string sPlainText = "";
int counter = 0;
int iAccept = 0;
do
{
    if(argc != 2) // <-----this should work whats wrong?
        {
            printf("Invalid argument! Please enter program name and         keyword.\n");
            return 1;
        }
    else if(argv[1])
        {
        for(int i = 0; i < iKeyLength; i++)
            {
                if (!isalpha(argv[1][i]))
                {
                    printf("Invalid entry, please use letters   only.\n");
                    return 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    iAccept = 1;
                }
            }
        }    
}while(iAccept == 0);


for(int i = 0; i < iKeyLength; i++)           
    {
        iKey[i] = toupper(sKeyWord[i]) - 65;     
    }

sPlainText = GetString();                    
int iPlainText = strlen(sPlainText);        


for(int j = 0; j < iPlainText; j++)
    {
        if(!isalpha(sPlainText[j]))
            {
                printf("%c",sPlainText[j]);
                counter++;
            }
        if(islower(sPlainText[j]))
            {
                printf("%c",((((sPlainText[j] - 97) + iKey[(j - counter)%iKeyLength])%26)+ 97));
            }
        if(isupper(sPlainText[j]))
            {
                printf("%c",((((sPlainText[j] - 65) + iKey[(j - counter)%iKeyLength])%26)+ 65));
            }

    }
printf("\n");

return 0;
}
```

Comment: you should investigate in more early.  E.g before `string sKeyWord = argv[1];`

Comment: DOH! thanks bluepixy *High Five* my savior! changed to string skeyWord = ""; and then assigned argv[1] to it at end of do while loop.

Comment: Why are you checking the arguments in a do-while loop? (Hint: I think you do not need this code to be in a loop.)

Comment: Why? Cause I am a noob lol. Will look into that. After moving some things around I broke the encryption process. Will try to debug it myself tonight.

Comment: @luser droog ok I updated my OP to the code I have now. everything works except when a 'z' is used in the keyword. it shifts the plaintext the wrong way. all other letters work fine it seems. here is my check50

Comment: Do not revise the question so that it bears so little relationship to the original (though I suppose that since you don't have a formal answer, maybe the revision should be allowed — but in general, don't transform a question so that previous help is no longer relevant). If need be, show a revised version of the code (as well as the original). You should also show sample inputs and expected outputs and actual outputs. Your 'check all characters in the key are alphabetic' code was looking dubious to me. Subtracting `65` rather than `'A'` is problematic — though assuming non-EBCDIC could be too.

Comment: @Firecore Make a new question for the revised code's new problem.

Comment: Why assume that people know what you are referring to with `cs50`? That isn't a standard header. It seems like something which is used in some undergraduate CS courses.

Comment: Apologies, new to programming, stack overflow and cs in general. Thanks for the advice. Will make a new question.

Answer (score 0):

I'd rewrite the top, argument handling section of your program like this.

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{  
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s key\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }
    char *sKeyWord = argv[1];                   
    int iKeyLength = strlen(sKeyWord);           
    int iKey[iKeyLength];                        

    for (int i = 0; i < iKeyLength; i++)
    {
        if (!isalpha(sKeyword[i]))
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "%s: Invalid character '%c' in key; please use letters only.\n",
                    argv[0], sKeyword[i]);
            return 1;
        }
        iKey[i] = toupper(sKeyWord[i]) - 'A';
    }

    …your code to read the text to be enciphered and encipher it, etc…
```

The key point is to check that there is an `argv[1]` before trying to do anything with it.  I eliminated a `do { … } while (…);` loop because the argument isn't going to change on a second iteration.  That allows the `iAccept` variable to be eliminated.  Note that errors are reported on standard error, not standard output.  Also notice that the messages are preceded by the program name (`argv[0]`).  A 'Usage' message is often the best way to report a problem; it's a simple reminder to those who run the program what's required.  Note too that the error message for the alphabetic check reports the erroneous character; that helps people see what the program thinks is wrong.

This is more or less what the comments were suggesting should be done.

I've not reviewed the enciphering code; there could be undiagnosed problems in that too.  There are many related questions on SO that would provide you with answers to any such problems, though.